# New Line is replaced by a single space in rich:tree

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have Lists of messages in a `<div>` as:

```
<div id="abc" class="icon111" title="#{collection.message}" />
```

This `<div>` is included in the JSF Rich-tree.

When `switchType="ajax"` for `rich:tree` the messages before expanding the tree is displaying properly, but once tree is expanded, all the messages are coming in one line(new line is replaced with the single space).

If I change the `switchType="server/client"` it will work, but it will impact in the performance of my project so I have to go with ajax only.

Is there anyway to display the messages in different lines?

Comment: you know that html itself does not do anything with 'new lines' do you?

Comment: Yes, I have added the "line.separator" in Java class for new line.From Java if debug before xhtml, all messages are in diffrent line.But when div it is under rich:tree and use the 'switchType="ajax"' then only the problem after first ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding messages in java keep some Separator add list of messages to div title , but when mouseover div call JS , inside JS function Split the messages to next line with Regular expression

```
<div id="**abc**" class="icon111" title="#{collection.message}" onmouceover="showTitle('#{collection.message}','**abc**');/>
function showTitle(value,id){
var divContent = jQuery("#" + id);
var newTitle=value.replace(/#/g, '\n');
divContent.attr('title', newTitle);
```

}
Div id should dynamic , because Rich tree will take same div for all the hierarchy in the tree